# heroku pg:psql error: cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to access my production postgresql database on heroku using the following command from a windows command line:

```
> heroku pg:psql
```

However, I am getting the below error.  I made sure that net-ssh is included in my gemfile with *gem 'net-ssh', '2.9.3.beta1'*, then I deleted gemfile.lock, and re-deployed.  Any help is appreciated!

```
---> Connecting to DATABASE_URL
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0/lib/net/ssh/gateway.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/heroku_postgresql.rb:54:in `maybe_tunnel'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:150:in `psql'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:212:in `run'
    from C:/Users/user/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:30:in `start'
    from C:/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you run any other `heroku` command? Like `heroku run rails c`

Comment: Yes, I am able to...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It had something to do with a version of Ruby that I installed after I installed the Heroku toolbelt.  So I just uninstalled and reinstalled the Heroku toolbelt like so:

1. Go to Add / Remove Programs and uninstall the Heroku Toolbelt
2. Install the Heroku Toolbelt from https://toolbelt.heroku.com/
3. Type in heroku in a command line to install the toolbelt

I hope this helps someone.